# Angular 5, Webpack 3. AoT breaks routing with parameters

Tags: angular, webpack, routes, angular-aot

This is my working router in the dev environment.

```
const WEBAPP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'feed', component: LiveFeedComponent},
  { path: 'register-line', component: RegisterLineComponent},
  { path: 'rides', component: RidesComponent},
  { path: 'track', component: TrackPageComponent},
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
  { path: 'user', redirectTo: 'user/'+localStorage.getItem('username'), pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'user/:id', component: ProfileComponent}
];
```

However it break after AoT build, and gives this output, when trying to access the web app.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route 'user'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

I've tried defining the routes in childs like this: (which also worked with the dev enviroment).

```
const WEBAPP_ROUTES: Routes = [
// { path: '**', redirectTo: 'feed', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'feed', component: LiveFeedComponent},
  { path: 'register-line', component: RegisterLineComponent},
  { path: 'rides', component: RidesComponent},
  { path: 'track', component: TrackPageComponent},
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
  { path: 'user', children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: localStorage.getItem('username'), pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: ':id', component: ProfileComponent }
    ]}
];
```

How come the error messages doesn't even make sense?

EDIT: 
Related github discussion: [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20249)

Comment: 'One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren' is that not provided? and runtime route config?

Comment: Are you not getting the `username` item from `localStorage` at runtime? Therefore, AOT becomes problematic. If the compiler can't resolve the value *ahead-of-time*, then it thinks it has not been provided.

Comment: how would i get runtime information to the router then? - If I want to do the desired redirect? url/user redirects to the user's own profile.

Comment: I want to say just have the `ProfileComponent` component read the `username` item from `localStorage` directly. I would think that would do the trick. Do you really need to pass the value on the URL when you have it stored?

Comment: I want their routing to be unique. so user/user1 and user/user2 are served as a profile lookup. redirecting is for redirecting to user's own profile